# Attach to process after application close

Tags: java, processbuilder

My application can start custom processes using ProcessBuilder, I have methods to trigger "commands" and also to join the process console to see output. I am saving all the started processes and information in memory, but the problem is that when the application closes I lose all the track of the started/saved processes, what is the best way for when the application starts be able to obtain all the initialized processes & information again?

Comment: This is a task for JNI. JNI is a lower level C++ interface for java. You can call C++ code via dll to give you the needed process ID(PID) and other information you want. If you want to learn more about JNI, I suggest you read a book. This is a good book "The Java Native Interface: Programmer's Guide and Specification (The Java Series)"

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly vague question, but I'll do my best. I'd suggest looking up java shutdown hooks, so that a block of code can run after the main app finishes that saves the data somewhere, like a text file or a database. Then on startup, you can look at that text file or database to load the info into memory